# Modifying member variables with QtConcurrent::run()?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Let's say I have a class `MyClass` that contains a function that is really complex and slow `slowFunction()` that I want to be executed in another thread, for this I'm using **Qtconcurrent::run**, here is a snippet:

```
void MyClass::startAnalysis() {
     //Run slowFunction in another thread
     QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::slowFunction);
}

void MyClass:slowFunction() {
     for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         qDebug() << this << i;
     }
}
```

The main problem that I'm facing is if `slowFunction()` performs any operation over a member variable of `MyClass` I get (eventually) a crash. Also, as in the code above, when I try to output the pointer `this` I also get a crash!.

Is there anything wrong with modifying member variables inside a function executed by QtConcurrent::run ?

Comment: Most probably the instance of `MyClass` is destructed, before the thread starts to run. Could you post the code where you invoke `startAnalysis`?

Comment: The proper instance of MyClass doesn't get destructed, I'm sure of it.

Comment: The problem is most probably not in the code you shows us, that is why we wont be able to help unless you reveal more on your problem.

Comment: I did not reproduce the crash on "this" with the code sample you're providing.

Comment: A bit more code would help, but personally I agree with Yuki, your 'this' probably is deleted while your slow function still uses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to protect the access to your member variables with a QMutex.

```
void MyClass 
{
...
private:
QMutex mutex;
}
```

Then whenever you access a variable used by your concurrent, you protect it with a lock.

```
{
QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
// access variable
}
```

There is nothing wrong in modifying member variables in a thread or a QConcurrent, but you need to protect it.

Comment: In fact this was the main problem, inside my 'slowFunction()' I had calls to a library that it wasn't thread safe. So adding proper mutex inside that library did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In this example if I use a QFuture the class instance stays alive as long as needed.

```
class MyClass : QObject {
public:
    void LongFunction() {
        for( int count = 0; count < 5; count++ ) {
            sleep( 1 );
            std::cout << "Ping long!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void run_c() {
        QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &MyClass::LongFunction);
    }


};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass c;
    c.run_c();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forget future.waitForFinished() https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfuture.html#waitForFinished